# cruising with a Schengen visa from a British port

Tags: visas

I have booked back to back cruises out of Tilbury, England.
I arrive from Asia into The U.K.then take several tour including
a day trip through the Chunnel from London to Paris and back, not spending the night there. Cruise departs Tilbury then docks
in Netherlands then several times in Norway then cruise 1 ends
in the AM in Tilbury then departs same afternoon from Tilbury,
docks in Denmark, then 3 nights in Iceland then docks in the
Scottish islands then returns to Tilbury, after which I return
home to Asia. How many entry visa do I need for the U.K., and
how many entry Schengen Visa is required?

An Old Pro Traveller

Comment: Depending on citizenship: UK Tourism Visitor visa ; Schengen Multiple entry visa.

Comment: The standard U.K. visitor visa is multi-entry with a 6 month validity period.